# Instagram Type Mode View

Tags: java, android, instagram, textview

[image]I need to create Text mode same as Instagram Type Mode in Status . 
I created it from this [reference](https://instagram-engineering.com/building-type-mode-for-stories-on-ios-and-android-8804e927feba). I can manage the size with respect to width but can't control the height ratio, need logic to control both height and width.

Comment: what you have done to manage width please show your code snippet.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Here is the [link](https://hastebin.com/koviwabawu.java) of my code. Thanks in advance.